# Exist any API to retrieve demographic information about an specific areacode located in USA?

Tags: usa, api, demographics, census

Does any API retrieve demographic information about a specific area code located in the USA?

Comment: Assuming you're referring to Phone Number area code, I don't think the Census Bureau provides that geographic delineation. As far as ZIP Codes, the Census Bureau provides an approximation of that with ZIP Code Tabulation Areas (ZCTA's).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using ZIP code. There is the guideline about https://towardsdatascience.com/getting-census-data-in-5-easy-steps-a08eeb63995d and official Census API